# how to get annotations defined on a type from TypeAnnotation dart analyzer

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I want to get TypeAnnotation source to get annotations defined on that type

// file1.dart

```
@Annoation(name :"hello")
class RType { }
```

// file2.dart

```
    @Selectors()
    class Example {
      static Rtype hello() => null;
    }
```

by using ast visitor i am able to get RType ( TypeAnnoation) , but i want to get actual RType and its annotations ..

```
class SelectorsGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<Selectors> {

AstNode getAstNodeFromElement(Element element) {
  AnalysisSession session = element.session;
  ParsedLibraryResult parsedLibResult =
      session.getParsedLibraryByElement(element.library);
  ElementDeclarationResult elDeclarationResult =
      parsedLibResult.getElementDeclaration(element);
  return elDeclarationResult.node;
}

  @override
  generateForAnnotatedElement(
      Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep) {
    if (!(element is ClassElement)) {
      throw Exception("Selectors should be applied on class only");
    }
    element = element as ClassElement;

    final visitor = ExampleVisitor();
    final astNode = getAstNodeFromElement(element);
    astNode.visitChildren(visitor);

    return """
       // Selector
    """;
  }
}


class ExampleVisitor extends SimpleAstVisitor {
        
     @override
     visitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclaration node) {
             final t= node.returnType; //TypeAnnonation
              t.type // DartType is null here :( 
              //TODO i want to get annotations defined on this type 
        
           }
        }
```

Comment: How are you loading the AST? If you fetch it after the element model has been loaded, the type references should be resolved.

Comment: @simolus updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to switch to the AST model for this, it should be possible to get the annotation with the Element model.

```
var methods = classElement.methods;
for (var method in methods) {
  var returnType = method.returnType;
  var metadata = returnType.element.metadata;
  // Do something with the annotation.
}
```

Comment: I need AST because i want to go through method body to find PropertyAccess nodes of some variable, any reason why type is null in AST code ?

Comment: You are probably ended up an at unresolved AST there